# How to run my iOS app on iOS emulator (like emu/cider app) in Android?

Tags: android, ios, app-store

*This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so sorry in advance if I asked the question in the wrong place or messed up.*

I have this project where I am repurposing an old android tablet for the project. I need to make an app which will always be open on the tablet. The problem is, I am not proficient in making apps for Android. So, I thought let me run an iOS emulator (like iemu or Cider APK). Then, I realized I don't know how to put my app on the emulator.

I was thinking of [ad hoc](http://3qilabs.com/how-to-ad-hoc-distribute-your-ios-app-via-a-website-and-ota), but I am not sure if it will work. Then I though about stuff like Snapchat ++ or Instagram ++. How do they distribute it? For those who are unfamiliar with it watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81XZyUiH1Sk) starting at 1:55.

So in short, can I put my iOS app on the emulator or is it just better to get better at making android apps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I need to make an app which will always be open on the tablet" -- that is difficult to do when writing a native Android app. Kiosk mode on Android 5.0+ may help, but "old android tablet" suggests that you are not running 5.0 or higher. In that case, you're in a world of hurt, and that's even before this idea of running an iOS app in an emulator (which has gotta be slow). Why not just buy a used iPad?

Comment: I didn't think about that… I'm pretty sure it is running above android 5.0, but yea. I can't buy an iPad, but thx for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Based on my quick research I checked just briefly bunch of articles about Cider APK or iEMU APK and also comments and I downloaded one app but didn't run it because its basically distributed from some google drive account and looks quite dangerous to run on my phone.

But based on my understanding how this is actually doable https://appetize.io looks like only way, as this is merely some remote virtualization solution and they have business model instead of ad scam business model as those others. appetize.io runs in browser and has a free plan with limitations but usable , also they allow to upload your apk to their server to run it on their iOS devices that is basically visible in web browser, while quite slow but working and its real thing and useful.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you would get Cider APK or iEMU APK.
I have never done it myself but I know it's doable. Read their documentation.
Install the emulator in your IDE and run by choosing the desired destination.
Hope this helps.
http://www.androidcrush.com/run-ios-apps-on-android/

Comment: Thanks for answering. But one follow up question what do you mean be install the emulator in my IDE. The IDE is Xcode (its a iOS app), but how would I install the emulator in Xcode.

Comment: you said you want to run your app in android. so i would guess you somehow have to install in your android ide the ios simulators.
If you want to run ios app on ios simulator they should be built in, or you can add them via the simulators manager inside xcode.
install the simulator in the ide where your code is written. then you should be good.

Comment: ohh. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would like to suggest @AdrianBorcea to try first before you propose solutions because as it seems to me based on my research both Cider APK or iEMU APK are typical ad scam apps. Not useful for developers wanting to test iOS app in any way. Basically they just replace launcher to mimics ios appearance while providing adds and authors created quite hype with various articles while unexperienced users and others just help to spread this ...